# Map NTFS permission to SharePoint library permission?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

We have folder on the server which is shared by many users. The permission is based on NTFS. Now, we want to put this folder in sharepoint as a library, Is there a way to automatically convert the NTFS based permission to sharepoint permission?

Or, we have to manage the permission in sharepoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom code to convert NTFS based permissions to sharepoint based permissions.

There are lot of 3rd party softwares available to map the NTFS permissions that you can look.

http://caribbeandms.com/cdms/index.php/products/sharepoint-extenders/dockit-for-sharepoint

http://documents.software.dell.com/DOC150697